# "is processed" or "was processed"?

Tags: c++, naming

In a program I'm working on, I'm trying to describe an item that was processed a certain way in a previous iteration. I want the function I write that is used to access this state to be as self-describing as possible. The function name could be:

```
wasProcessedAsMime()
```

or

```
isProcessedAsMime()
```

Which is more correct or makes the most sense? "processed" itself is past-tense, but I'm not sure if "was" or "is" is necessary before it. The former sounds more natural, but I'm not sure why. Are both valid? If so, what do each mean?

I was also told that `hasBeenProcessedAsMime()` would be the formally correct version, but I'm not sure if this is overkill :)

Comment: This would better be suited for something like http://english.stackexchange.com, but there's most likely a dupe in its own way somewhere.

Comment: @chris I JUST deleted this very same question on english.stackexchange.com because in their FAQ it says NO naming questions related to programming.

Comment: I guess there are some programming elements thrown in. If they do make a difference, I can see how they wouldn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, if the return type is Boolean (which it probably is), I would use isProcessedAsMime(), because that is conventional and helps with self-describing the function for the next person who maintains your code.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. Just use `processedAsMime`

Comment: Or indicative of the source: `HasMimeSource`, or even better a more generic method `GetSourceType() == object::MIME`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with "isProcessed" since the object is in the state of having been processed, so the return here is True.